# wp_enqueue_script não funciona

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, xampp

Estou criando um tema para WordPress, porém o `wp_enqueue_scripts` não funciona. O código que está no `functions.php` é:

```
<?php
function scripts_and_styles() {

  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
      wp_register_style( 'style.css',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style.css' );
      wp_register_style( 'bootstrap.min.css','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min.css' );
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_and_styles');
?>
```

Outras informações que talvez ajudem a identificar o que está acontecendo:

- Quando insiro `echo 'Oi!';` aparece *Oi!* no `index.php`, como esperado;
- Tenho que inserir no `header.php` o `<?php do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts') ?>`, e pelo que havia entendido isto não seria necessário;
- Quando uso `var_dump` no `wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery' );` e nos outros `wp_enqueue_script()` é 'impresso' `NULL` no `index.php`;
- Nada que use `jQuery` funciona no meu tema (Creio que porque eu não consiga chamá-lo);
- Eu utilizo o `XAMPP`.

Só para deixar mais claro: **Não é só o jQuery que não funciona, nada é incluso. Não chama nem estilo e nem script.** Tenho ciência que o jQuery vem incluso no Wordpress e que tenho que apontar caso algum script dependa dele.

Comment: O que você precisa fazer que depende do jQuery? Quando aos styles, acredito que o handle esteja incorreto por conter a extensão do arquivo (mas não sei, não testei). Ainda sobre os styles, recomendo que você sirva uma cópia local do bootstrap, e não a partir de um cdn, esse downtime *pode* estar causando algum problema.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Muito obrigado pela disposição, mas o erro era outro faltava wp_head() e wp_footer()!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionei o problema adicionado o `wp_head()` e o `wp_footer()`!

Answer (score 2):

O jQuery, assim como [vários outros scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#notes), já vem incluso no *core* do WordPress, e eles funcionam *on-demand*, ou seja, apenas quando são necessários.

O que acontece é que, dentro da lógica do WP, você pode criar *scripts* dependentes de outros *scripts* sem se preocupar com a ordem de inclusão. Você apenas deixa clara a **dependência** que um *script* tem do outro, e deixa que o WP faça a inclusão na ordem correta.

Imagine que você tenha um *script* `animacoes.js` (que é dependente do jQuery), e você quer incluí-lo na sua página. Como o jQuery já existe no WP, você não precisa se preocupar com ele (que é o caso da primeira linha da sua condição `!is_admin()`. O que você precisa fazer é dizer pro WP que essa dependência existe, e que ele faça a inclusão, da seguinte maneira:

```
 wp_register_script('animacoes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/animacoes.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
```

Veja que aqui estou apenas **registrando** o script. Não estou fazendo a inclusão do mesmo propriamente dita. O método [`wp_register_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) recebe alguns parâmetros, que são:

1. O nome do *handler* do seu *script*. (A partir desse ponto, é esse nome que você vai referenciar no seu código);
2. O caminho do *script*;
3. Um *array* contendo os *handlers* das dependências. Veja que o *handler* do jQuery é `jquery`, com a letra `q` em caixa baixa. Caso você tenha mais de uma [dependência](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#notes), basta que você a inclua neste *array*;
4. A versão do seu *script*
5. Um *bool* para colocá-lo ou não no rodapé da página.

Depois de registrado, basta *enfileirar-lo*, usando o método [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), da seguinte maneira:

```
wp_enqueue_script('animacoes');
```

Onde o parâmetro é o *handler* do *script* previamente registrado.

O WordPress tem o cuidado de trabalhar com o jQuery no modo [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), em virtude de outras bibliotecas que podem usar o `$` e mais uma série de motivos que não vem ao caso. Você pode ter tentado abrir o console no seu site e rodado `$('html').addClass('classe')` (ou basicamente qualquer outra coisa usando o método `$()`), e ter acabado recebendo um `$ is not defined`. Isso ocorre justamente por conta desse modo. Se você rodar `jQuery('html').addClass('classe')`, vai ver que tudo dá certo.

Para contornar esse fato, e usar `$` sem problema no seu *script* `animacoes`, você pode fazer algo como o seguinte:

```
//animacoes.js
(function($){

    $('html').addClass('class');
    // code...

}) (jQuery);
```

Basicamente, dentro desse *script*, você está dizendo que `$` deve ser resolvido pelo jQuery.

Essa é a maneira mais habitual de se trabalhar com *scripts* dentro do WP. Pode até parecer meio estranho no inicio, mas você pega o jeito logo logo. Lembre-se em sempre usar o que a ferramenta já disponibiliza. Trabalhar registrando e "desregistrando" *scripts* pode acabar sendo altamente não produtivo.

Comment: Não era isso que eu queria, mas votei pela sua disposição, descobri o erro! É muito elementar, faltava o wp_head() e o wp_footer() !

Comment: @RafaelFD Acontece! Depois dessa vc nunca mais esquece.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer dessa forma:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // remove o registro se houver
wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Comment: eu tentei não funciona nada do tipo, mas mesmo assim, agradeço por ter dedicado seu tempo buscando ajudar!